# Stop background jobs after exiting the shell

Tags: shell

I use nohup to start several background jobs. Then I can use `job -l` to display those jobs and use `fg jobID` to put them front and stop them. But now I have quitted the session and after I login again and use "job -l" to display jobs, as expected, it displays nothing. Now, I want to know now could I stop those background jobs? Is there anyway similar to use `fg jobpid` to put it front and kill it?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use ps command to get the pid of the process and use kill command to kill the process by pid.

Comment: I am afraid it doesn't work well, because the job starts  process one by one.

Comment: You don't need to put the process in front, to be able to kill them. Just kill them, I don't see the problem. Use `PS` to monitor your processes. What can be an issue, is that your NOHUP process, started off different sub-processes itself, but still, that is nothing you can't solve with `PS` and `KILL`. - Alternatively, if you don't use NOHUP, your processes will be killed nicely by the system, if you terminate the Telnet shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (be careful, it can be dangerous):

```
ps -ef | grep 'some string int the process command' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: Yeah, it works:) I gets the parent pid first and kill it. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like tmux or screen and detach from the shell, when you log back in re-attach to the shell and run your normal commands as if you'd been logged in the whole time.